# Format exported data from database to a text file

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to group and write a data from SQL to a text file in a desired format? If so, how and what is the proper approach for this? This is the current code I have and users can select which month and year of data should be exported.

```
$user = $sanitize->for_db($_POST['user']);
$date = $_POST['date'];
$period = explode("-", $date);
    
$row = $database->get_assoc("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `user`='".$user."' AND YEAR(date)='".$period[0]."' AND MONTH(date)='".$period[1]."' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
    
if( !$row )
{
    $error[] = "Sorry, there was an error and the data was not exported.";
}

else
{
    $file = 'path/to/'.$user.'.txt';
    $fh = fopen($file, 'a');
    $last = end($row);
            
    foreach( $row as $item )
    {
        fwrite($fh, $item);
        if( $item != $last )
        {
            fwrite($fh, " | ");
        }
    }
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
    fclose($fh);

    $success[] = "Your data has been exported successfully!";
}
```

However, this code will write the data as:

```
User | lorem ipsum | 2022-02-15
User | dolor sit amet | 2022-02-15
User | consectetur adipiscing elit | 2022-02-20
```

So, is it possible to get a desired format like the one below?

```
2022-02-15 -----
- lorem ipsum
- dolor sit amet

2022-02-20 -----
- consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Any answer/help is highly appreciated! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why not modify your logic to return in any format of your choosing?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it be possible, do you think? What's the actual problem? What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Please update the question with your attempt to solve it, and the issue you're having. If you haven't attempted it, why not? Is there some gap in your knowledge you'd like to ask about, which is preventing you from understanding what to do, and which you cannot fill by researching? You mainly need to start monitoring the date on each row, and deciding whether to output a new date, or just a new value, accordingly.

Comment: @ADyson Hi! Apparently I've tried changing the code before but then deleted those changes when I wasn't able to get it to work. However, Mehrdad's question opened a new idea and I got it working by changing the foreach loop to while loop so I can get the format that I need. I thought it wasn't 100% possible so I asked. Thank you though! ^_^

Comment: Why, WHY you try to solve on PHP the task which can be easily solved within MySQL only? `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` can select the data from the table(s) and write it to text file in needed format.

Comment: @Akina I'm sorry, it's because I don't fully understand how it works. :(

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mehrdad for that brilliant question! It gave me an idea how to solve this hurdle.

I changed the `foreach loop` to `while loop` to get my desired format.

```
$user = $sanitize->for_db($_POST['user']);
$date = $_POST['date'];
$period = explode("-", $date);

$row = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `user`='$user' AND `date` LIKE '$date-%' ORDER BY `date` DESC");

if( !$row )
{
    $error[] = "Sorry, there was an error and the data was not exported.";
}

else
{
    $file = 'path/to/'.$user.'.txt';
    $fh = fopen($file, 'a');
    $timestamp = '';
    $output = '';

    while( $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $row ) )
    {
        if( $r['date'] != $timestamp )
        {
            $output = $output."".date('F d, Y', strtotime($r['date']))." -----\n";
            $timestamp = $r['date'];
        }
        $output = $output."- ".$r['data']."\n";
    } // end while
        
    fwrite($fh, $output);
    fclose($fh);

    $success[] = "Your data has been exported successfully!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(`date`,
              ' -----',
              GROUP_CONCAT('\n- ', `text_column` SEPARATOR ''))
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `user`='$user' 
  AND YEAR(`date`)='$period[0]' 
  AND MONTH(`date`)='$period[1]'
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date`

INTO OUTFILE 'X:\\folder\\output.txt'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\n'
;
```

This code will select your data in needed format and save into text file.

Alternatively you may select this in your program (remove INTO OUTFILE part, add an alias to the output expression) and save the output into text file as provided, without additional processing.